# Android Navigation Drawer & recyclerview onclick new Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick, android-recyclerview

I watched a nice Tutorial Video about creating a Navigation Drawer and using custom listView with RecycleView. The NaviDrawer works fine , but when I tried to do it  myself using onClick methods, I failed. Can anyone tell me what have I done wrong and how to make my code better?

**NavigationDrawer**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
    public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private Adapter adapter;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private View containerView;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPref(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) ;
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);


        adapter = new Adapter(getActivity(), getData());

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
if(view == "MainActivity")
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this, SubActivity.class));
        }

        if(view == "page 2")
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this, Page_2.class));
        }

        if(view == "page 3")
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(NavigationDrawerFragment.this, Page_3.class));
        }
            }


            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }

        ));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new

                LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()

        ));
        return layout;


    }


    public static List<Information> getData()


    {
        List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] icons = {R.drawable.ic_action_favorite, R.drawable.ic_action_group, R.drawable.ic_action_important};
        String[] titles = {"MainActivity", "page 2", "page 3"};
        for (int i = 0; i < titles.length && i < icons.length; i++) {

            Information current = new Information();
            current.iconId = icons[i];
            current.title = titles[i];
            data.add(current);

        }
        return data;
    }


    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        containerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveToPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer + "");

                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }


            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

            }
        };

        if (mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);

        }
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
    }


    public static void saveToPreference(Context context, String prefName, String prefValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(prefName, prefValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readFromPref(Context context, String prefName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getString(prefName, defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}

class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private ClickListener clickListener;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {

                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
                super.onLongPress(e);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongClick(View view, int position);

    }
}
```

---

**Adapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter< Adapter.myViewHolder> {

    List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private Context context;
    private ClickListener clickListener;
    private LayoutInflater inflator;


    public Adapter(Context context, List<Information> data) {
        inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.costom_row, parent, false);
        myViewHolder holder = new myViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Information current = data.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(current.title);
        holder.icon.setImageResource(current.iconId);


    }
    public void setClickListener(ClickListener clickListener){
        this.clickListener=clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    //Image + Text von dem Drawer
    class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icon;

        public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listText);
            icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.listIcon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    }
    public interface ClickListener{
        public void itemClicked(View view,int position);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toolbar;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);

        toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  //das Icon womit man den Drawer Schließt/Öffnet
        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_0), toolbar);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.navigate) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Information.java**
(holds the "Titles" as strings and the icons i use )

```
public class Information {
    int iconId;
    String title;
}
```

**the costom_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="heyyyy"
        android:textSize="22dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**the main_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.dima.myapplication.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**NaviDrawerLayout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primaryColor"
    tools:context="com.example.dima.myapplication.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:id="@+id/rela">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerDrawerImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageBarney"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_background_two" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/containerDrawerImage">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there are a couple of things which are wrong in your code, without testing your code I can see that comparing a string with a View is wrong.

Comment: i know but i tried to show how i would like to have it right.